# How to do scroll screen with a lot of widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to do scroll screen with many widget.I want to use with  carouselSlider, card, text and listTile widget.I used listview with gridview and i got error,i used gridView because i want to use card widget side by side and one after one other.
I have bad english, i am sorry

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a SingleChildScrollView ?

Comment: Did you wrap the ListView with Expanded? Always wrap the listview widget with expanded when it return the widgets

Answer (score 1):

A scrolling screen can be created using:

```
return Scaffold(
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Column(
          children: [
             //Put the widget code you want here.
          ],
       ),
   ),
);
```

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListView as parent and GridView as child with shrinkWrap true property like this

```
ListView(
  children: [
    // First item in the ListView is a GridView
    GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    // Second item in the ListView is a simple ListTile
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Item 2'),
    ),
    // Third item in the ListView is another GridView
    GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.brown,
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    // Fourth item in the ListView is another ListTile
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Item 4'),
    ),
  ],
);
```